# Proving a vector equality in a triangle without using Thales' theorem.

Tags: analytic-geometry, affine-geometry, vectors

> **Problem**
>
> Let $\text{ABC}$ be a triangle, and $\text{M}$ and $\text{N}$ are points where: $\vec{\text{AM}}=\frac{1}{3}\vec{\text{AB}}$ and $\vec{\text{AN}}=\frac{1}{2}\vec{\text{AB}}$ and $\text{M'}$ and $\text{N'}$ are points in $\text{[AC]}$ such that both $\text{(NN')}$ and $\text{(MM')}$ are parallel to $\text{(BC)}$
>
> 1. Write $\vec{\text{AM'}}$ and $\vec{\text{AN'}}$ with respect to $\vec{\text{AC}}$, then conclude that $\vec{\text{MM'}}=\frac{1}{3}\vec{\text{BC}}$ and $\vec{\text{NN'}}=-\frac{1}{2}\vec{\text{BC}}$
> 2. Conclude that $\frac{\text{MM'}}{\text{NN'}}=\frac{2}{3}$
>
> To have a  better idea of what it may look like:
>
> [image]

Here's my try:

- Prove that $\vec{\text{AM'}}$ is equal to $1/3$ of $\vec{\text{AC}}$ using Thales' theorem:

  - $\text{(AM')} \| \text{(AC)}$
  - $\text{A is in [AC)}$
  - $\|\vec{\text{AM'}}\|=\frac{1}{3}\|\vec{\text{AC}}\|$

But I can't use Thales' theorem, so how to proceed?

Comment: The diagram doesn't match the data. The two points on $AB$ should be one at midpoint and one closer to $A$ than $B$ and also the lines drawn should be parallel to $BC$ from data and not to $AC$ as in the diagram.

Comment: Are you sure about the minus sign in $\vec{\text{NN'}}=-\frac{1}{2}\vec{\text{BC}}$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath Of course, the diagram doesn't match  the data, it's just to give an idea.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I made a mistake since AN=-1/2AB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Start from $\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}+\vec{CA}=0$ and multiply it respectively by $1/3$ and by $1/2$ to get equations containing $\vec{AM},\vec{MM'},\vec{M'A}$ and the same with $N,N'$ replacing $M,M'$. Then use that the length of $kV$ is $k$ times the length of $V$, for a positive constant $k$, and also that $\vec{VW}=-\vec{WV}.$ 
For the $2/3$ ratio, note it comes from $(1/3)/(1/2)$ at the appropriate point.

Comment: " and multiply it respectively by 1/3 and by 1/2 to get equations containing AM→,MM′→,M′A→ " I don't understand this part.

Comment: $AM=(1/3)AB$ is given. You have $(1/3)AB+(1/3)BC+(1/3)CA=0$, and $1/3(BC)$ is parallel to $BC$. So renaming $A,B,C$ as $A,M,M'$ in this gives a triangle whose sides are parallel to those of the given triangle $ABC$. This uses that a nonzero multiple of a vector is parallel to it.

Comment: Thanks                                       ! That's very helpful.